# How do I get the latest version of Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

ios xcode build-->run console message

- Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.0.26137.0
- New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 2.3.30035.0

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

manualy download version is GoogleMaps-2.0.1

How do I get the latest ver.2.3.30035 for manual installation?

- COCOAPODS is not used.

Comment: Check again. It says v2.3.0 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Comment: thanx.  check again.Japanese Language: https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/5a212b0fa429156f-GoogleMaps-2.0.1.tar.gz

v2.3.0 not download.

Comment: found url
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/2.3.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json

  "source": {
    "http": "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/5356613c00d555f4/GoogleMaps-2.3.1.tar.gz"
  },